# Trying to shorten some code, getting -1 return values

Tags: integer, int, return

So right now i have this code -

```
private int getPinForComponent(final int componentId,
        final boolean lastDigit) {
    if (lastDigit) {
        switch (componentId) {
        case 6:
            return 0;
        case 7:
            return 1;
        case 8:
            return 2;
        case 9:
            return 3;
        case 10:
            return 4;
        case 11:
            return 5;
        case 12:
            return 6;
        case 13:
            return 7;
        case 14:
            return 8;
        case 15:
            return 9;
        }
    } else {
        switch (componentId) {
        case 4:
            return 0;
        case 8:
            return 1;
        case 12:
            return 2;
        case 16:
            return 3;
        case 20:
            return 4;
        case 24:
            return 5;
        case 28:
            return 6;
        case 32:
            return 7;
        case 36:
            return 8;
        case 40:
            return 9;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

That all seems to be working fine, it simply returns a value of 0-9 depending on which component is clicked. I've been trying to shorten it and i came up with this..

```
private int getPinForComponent(int componentId, boolean lastDigit) {
    if (lastDigit) {
        return componentId - 6;
    } else {
        return ((componentId / 12) * 3) - 1;
    }
}
```

And that returns -1 values alot or just wrong values.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Try to debug and look what value componentId has.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(lastDigit) {
    if (componentId >= 6 && componentId <= 15) {
        return componentId - 6;               
    }
} else {
    if (componentId % 4 == 0 && componentId >= 4 && componentId <= 40) {
        return (componentId / 4) - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `(componentId + 4) % 10` instead of the original `componentId - 6`?

Comment: @ChrisCulter It would be the same but still edited answer as it is cleaner. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use the modulus operator.

```
if(lastDigit) {
    return (componentId+4) % 10;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, how would i use this with something like this.

((componentId / 12) * 3) - 1;

Comment: @CodyMiddleton where your code says 'if(lastDigit) {' you would put this code in the same place, in place of the switch.

Comment: got that far but just trying to understand it.
so its just saying return the componentId + 4 then times by 10%?

Comment: @CodyMiddleton % is the modulus operator.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that `((componentId / 12) * 3) - 1` is sometimes evaluated as `-1`. In most languages, if `componentId` is an integer type, and its value is less than 12, then `(componentId / 12)` is rounded down to 0, and then `(0 * 3) - 1` equals `-1`.

In the real numbers, which are used in pure mathematics, dividing by 12 and multiplying by 3 is the same as dividing by 4. But when rounding gets involved, these two sequences of operations are different. That's the theory behind why sujithvm's answer works, even though at first glance it might appear to do the same thing as the buggy code in the question.

By the way, as a style issue... Why did the original switch-case code have to be shortened at all? It was working, and it was crystal-clear. The shortened versions are harder to understand, let alone update if the pins ever change.

Comment: I just prefer my code to be short and sweet. Don't like to make it look cluttered thats all, and i'm keen to learn the shorter methods.